# How to get all options from Groovy OptionAccessor?

Tags: groovy

I have the following:

```
final cli = new CliBuilder(...)
cli.with {...}

final arguments = cli.parse(args)
println arguments.properties
```

but no matter what, the output is:

```
false
```

How can I get all the options that were set?

Answer (score 1):

```
cli.options.getOptions()
    .findAll {
        arguments[it.key]
    }
    .each {
        println "${it.key}: ${arguments[it.key]}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple one-liner to print the values if you use named options:

```
def options = cli.parse(args)
println "Executing with options '${options.getOptions().collect{ o -> "${o.opt}=${o.value}"}.join(', ')}'"
```

and here with arguments:

```
def options = cli.parse(args)
println "Executing with arguments '${options.getArgs().join(', ')}'"
```